# Blender Game: Transparent Shadows

Tags: game-engine, transparency

I have a semi-transparent vase that casts a nice shadwo when I hit "p".

However, when I start the standalone player, the transparent material doesn't cast a shadow.

Any ideas why that could be?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Got it, had to change the transparency from "Z Transparency" to "Raytrace".

Edit: In the material settings you have "mask" "z transparency" and "raytrace" - just select the "raytrace" box.

Comment: oookay... would you mind adding more detail of your situation so we can help other people with the same problem?

Comment: Like a screenshot of the option